# removing ubuntu boot loader

Tags: boot

i use the dual os system that is windows7 and ubuntu 12.04. windows is installed on the c drive., but ubuntu is installed in a separate partition "F"drive...
Once i have installed the Ubuntu in the F drive..., but deleted the folder of Ubuntu by mistake.

Once again the i installed the Ubuntu....in the same drive..,
But now when i start the system..,the boot manager appears like., 
  Windows 7
  u buntu
  u Ubuntu

the extra option Ubuntu does not open but shows error.., and the other Ubuntu is working properly....and windows 7 as well.

Now how can i remove the extra Ubuntu option...,tried using the command prompt in windows but it displays..,no folder found.(or directory of Ubuntu)..it shows something like File:***/***/***/.mbr not found....

Answer (score 0):

Boot into ubuntu and enter in a terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

It should rebuild the options for the systems it finds installed on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Grub as boot loader then go into ubuntu, open terminal and run `sudo update-grub`

This will update the Grub boot loader with the correct boot systems.

Not sure how to do it, if you use Windows Boot Loader.